# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable when reading a file

Tags: python, file

I am trying to make a simple game in python, (I'm pretty new, don't hate me too much!) and I'm getting this error when I run this in the idle editor:

```
Do you have an account? Y or N: n
What is your username: password
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bright Bridge\Desktop\Personal\Python Projects\main.py", line 33, in <module>
    check_user_name()
  File "C:\Users\Bright Bridge\Desktop\Personal\Python Projects\main.py", line 17, in check_user_name
    if set_user_name() in read_file().format():
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

this is my code:

```
def create_file():
    security = open("user.txt", "r+") #I know it's called security, but it's
    security.write(set_user_name())   #not really secure...
    security.close()

def check_user_name():
    security = open("user.txt", "r")
    read_file = security.read()
    if set_user_name() in read_file().format():
        print("Welcome " + set_user_name())
        security.close()
    else:
        print("Invalid Username")
        security.close()

def login(username, password):
    pass

def set_user_name():
    user_name = input("What is your username: ")
    return user_name

account_check = input("Do you have an account? Y or N: ")
if account_check == "y" or "Y" or "yes" or "Yes" or "YES":
    check_user_name()
else:
    create_file()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read_file` is now a string containing the content of the file. What you're doing is basically typing `'happy'()`. Remove the '()' in `read_file()`.